# I uploaded same name file with the intention of it being saved as the new version. Instead, both versions got saved with same name (+docX) Help Please

Tags: sharepoint-online, file-upload, version-history

Both files with same name got saved. Only difference being that the newer one has the extension 'docx' instead of 'doc'. Can someone help please? I want the newer one to merge with the older one and exist as the latest version of the same file.

Answer (score 0):

So this is a common issue.
Ensure that you actually have versioning turned on if you want to retain previous versions.  It sound like you do have it enabled.

1. open the new .DOCX file in the Word desktop App.
2. Click ‘File’ —> ‘Save A Copy’.  Keep the current name and select the .DOC file extension from the dropdown beneath the file name field.
3. Next, ensure you have selected the same location as the file you are trying to overwrite/create a new version.
4. After performing step 3, click ‘Save’ - you will be prompted as to whether you want to overwrite the existing file (which will create a new version).  Respond in the affirmative.
5. Upon success, delete the newer .DOCX file.

If you have the “Check-In / Check-Out” functionality enabled in this library, you will need to Check-Out the document in SharePoint before step 1 and perform a Check-In after step 4.

Answer (score 0):

We cannot merge your file in SharePoint, it's recommend that you open the newer file in word and merge it manually.

After that, we recommend that you upload with the same document suffix, so you have the opportunity to replace the old document and keep the latest version:

[image]